# Editable Combobox Binding

Tags: wpf, vb.net, combobox

I have an editable combobox that I bind the name property from a list of objects to (QBD.Name). What I can't figure out is how to allow editing of those names - I keep getting an object reference error when I try to edit.

I believe I need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, but I'm not entirely sure how that works.

Here's the binding code:

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbBxQBDNames" Text="Please Select a QBD" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=QBDs, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" DisplayMemberPath="QBD.Name" SelectedValuePath="QBD.Name" IsEditable="True" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="auto" MinWidth="25" Margin="45,0,0,0" Foreground="Black"></ComboBox>
```

Here's the objects I'm binding to:

```
Public Class QBDs

Private QBDsLocal As New ObservableCollection(Of QBD)

Public Property QBDs As ObservableCollection(Of QBD)
    Get
        Return QBDsLocal
    End Get
    Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of QBD))
        QBDsLocal = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class


Public Class QBD
Private NameLocal As String

Public Property Name As String
    Get
        Return NameLocal
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        NameLocal = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

Also, when I select an object from the combobox, how can I have it's name displayed in the combobox? Currently, it remains blank.

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is with DisplayMemberPath.

try with DisplayMemberPath = "Name"

let me know if it fails.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get why this fails,Please see the Code i've written to test your problem.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" DisplayMemberPath="FName" SelectedValuePath="SName" Height="40" IsEditable="True" />
```

//My DataContext Goes here

```
public class Model
    {
        private string sName;

        public string SName
        {
            get { return sName; }
            set { sName = value; }
        }
        private string  fName;

        public string  FName
        {
            get { return fName; }
            set { fName = value; }
        }

    }
    public class ViewModel
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Model> myColl;

        public ObservableCollection<Model> MyCollection
        {
            get { return myColl; }
            set { myColl = value; }
        }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
            MyCollection.Add(new Model { FName = "Tony", SName = "Strark" });
            MyCollection.Add(new Model { FName = "Bruce", SName = "Wayne" });
            MyCollection.Add(new Model { FName = "Miranda", SName = "Frost" });

        }

    }
```

//and I ve set ViewModel as DataContext,

This works just fine for me please check it once,and please forgive me for not giving the code in VB .

Regards,
Kumar